# PHP shell_exec ssh connection

Tags: php, linux, ssh, shell-exec

I know this question has been asked before in many different ways but I'm still scratching my head over why I can't get this to work.

Firstly I have two SLES servers setup, these are Server A & Server B which are both running on a small private network which is only accessed by a dedicated team.

Server A is configured as a web server which is running Apache, PHP, MYSQL and ssh all of which are running problem free.

Server B is used to run menial tasks with ssh also installed and activated.

I have created my rsa key on Server A and installed it on Server B which when run at the command line logs me in straight away with out asking for a password. I have repeated this process for both root & nobody accounts on Server A.

I have added this a PHP page to Server A which looks like:

```
<?php
shell_exec('ssh root@192.162.0.5 ./StartTest.sh');

header("Location: archive.php?page=home"); 
?>
```

But when I run it it does not create my folder. If I run this from the command line it works for both (I think both, I can't recall if I did try this for the nobody account on the cli now) root & the nobody account. I even went as far as adding the nobody account to the root group but still no joy.

Have I missed some thing here. All I would like to do is connect from Server A to Server B via php & ssh to execute one command and redirect to a another page on the web site.

Any help would be graciously appreciated as my paracetamol stock is running low.

Comment: Maybe this helps: shell_exec might use another shell than yours. And under a different user. Find out which shell it uses and which user, then copy your .ssh configuration over there - or set the appropriate environment variables, whatever causes the issue. you can also output debug stuff with ssh, check the switches.

Comment: Also look into using PHPs built-in `ssh2_connect` and `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` and `ssh2_exec` to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The built-in SSH support George Cummins speaks of is non-existent.  It is an extension to PHP that's not included by default.  It has to be compiled separately and is notoriously difficult to setup / use.  My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks nigol this solution was effortless to setup.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm too late at this answer but maybe can help someone:

To use `shell_exec` and `ssh` you need to add as parameter to `ssh` these

> ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=quiet

So the command doesn't try to create .ssh folder and you have a clear output without log of `ssh`

Comment: Rather than turn off checking the host key I would add the host key to the known hosts file: `ssh-keyscan -H remote_host >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 2):

You said "I have added this a PHP page", so I will assume that you are executing this script via your web server, rather than as a standalone script.

As such, the script may not be running from the directory you expect. You should use absolute (rather than relative) paths to ensure that the script finds the `ssh` binary and your script:

```
shell_exec('/path/to/ssh root@192.162.0.5 /home/yourdirectory/scripts/StartTest.sh');
```

You will also need to confirm that the webserver user had permissions to execute ssh and the StartTest.sh script.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt reply. Yes sorry this page is executed from my web server. I shall try your suggestion tomorrow when I have access to the servers again.

Comment: I have opted for nigols solution but I thank you for your time looking at my question and for adding a little morsel of knowlege to my arsenal though.

Comment: shell_exec can capture error output too (useful for debugging) by appending `2>&1` to the end of the command.