# Is there way to scp within a local network, from PHP, with beginner programmer skills

Tags: php, macos, scp, lan

I have a local network behind a router, so addresses are like 192.168.1.xxx. I need php to get files from other systems in that network.  Looked into php ssh but (1) it's way beyond my skill level and (2) ssh_connect is not available on my installation.  I can do it with command line scp, but not php.  Is there something easier for a newbie to understand, using php, to get/put files between local systems?

Comment: What protocols do the other systems allow? FTP would be a simple one if available

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, will try both ways.

Answer (score 1):

First i though that you can use  PHP Functions: `shell_exec()`

`shell_exec('/path/to/ssh root@192.162.0.5 /home/yourdirectory/scripts/StartTest.sh');`

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php

**Update**
You can use this lib: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749185/14807111

```php
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749185/14807111

Answer (score 0):

you can try `exec()`/ `shell_exec` to execute shell script
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php